# Why did Bourbaki's Élements omit the theory of categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ho.history-overview, bourbaki

### QUESTION

They had plenty of time to adopt the theory of categories. They had Eilenberg, then Cartan, then Grothendieck. Did they feel that they have established their approach already, that it's too late to go back and start anew?

I have my very-very general answer: *World* is *Chaos*, *Mathematics* is a *Jungle*, Bourbaki was a nice *fluke*, but no fluke can last forever, no fluke can overtake Chaos and Jungle. I'd still like to have a much more complete picture.

### Appendix: CHRONOLOGY

- 1934:   Bourbaki's birth (approximate date);
- 1942-45:   Samuel Eilenberg & Saunders Mac Lane - functor, natural transformation, $K(\pi,n)$;
- 1946 & 1952: S.Eilenberg & Norman E. Steenrod publish "Axiomatic..." & "Foundations...";
- 1956: Henri Cartan & S.Eilenberg publish "Homological Algebra";
- 1957: Alexander Grothendieck publishes his "Tohoku paper", abelian category.

(*Please, feel free to add the relevant most important dates to the list above*).

Comment: Wasn't the Bourbaki treatise meant to be "pedagogical"? Perhaps (but I don't have objective information about this) at the time category theory was considered too advanced to be put in a foundational set of volumes...

Comment: Another note is that something like the "category of sets" is not a set. To talk about it, you need some axioms other than the strict ZFC axioms on which all of Bourbaki's math is based. Thus, to discuss category theory in ways that include its current practice, Bourbaki would need either to augment the existing foundations in one way or another, or to adapt some sort of unconventional and probably very awkward conventions that would make their category theory work in ZFC, probably at the price of making it much harder to use.

Comment: There are much more qualified people to comment here, but if I recall correctly, it was extensively discussed whether to include categories or not.

Comment: @Charles Staats If I remember correctly, they did not use full ZFC in early editions, they left out the axiom of replacement and used epsilon calculus for cardinal assignment. However, I think you can do a lot of elementary, insightful category theory without talking about categories of categories or something like that. Well–you need classes. But I do not think Bourbaki was dogmatic about not using classes.

Comment: @Qfwfq: Bourbaki certainly was not afraid of being unorthodox, was revolutionary (which is hard to believe today :-). Many at the time, and later too (e.g. Vladimir Arnold) had strong misgivings about Bourbaki philosophy. Bourbaki was considered by them and many others (not me :-) anything but pedagogical.

Comment: @Michael, if you have any reference (link) to a discussion among Bourbaki about theory of category I would be interested and grateful for it.

Comment: @Wlodimierz Holsztynski: A related discussion can be read in Armand Borel's *Twenty-five years with Nicolas Bourbaki* http://www.ams.org/notices/199803/borel.pdf on page 378, where a short account of the story of the *congrès du foncteur inflexible* is given. It discusses Grothendieck's proposal how they should treat sheaf theory and why that route wasn't chosen.

Comment: @Qfwfq: At least some of the members of Bourbaki did not view what was being done as a pedagogical exercise. For instance, "People just misused [Bourbaki's] books; they were never meant for university teaching..." - JP Serre. (http://sms.math.nus.edu.sg/smsmedley/Vol-13-1/An%20interview%20with%20Jean-Pierre%20Serre(CT%20Chong%20&%20YK%20Leong).pdf)

Comment: It seems to me that quid's answer, while not bad, was accepted a bit prematurely. In particular, there are people who have made a careful study of the available historical record; among MO users, I think Colin McLarty would be in a position to give a more complete and authoritative answer. I will see whether I can contact him, to alert him to this thread. 

Comment: I was also slightly suprised when seeing a relatively quick accept for this (type of) question.  

Comment: No disrespect to the author, but I have altered the title a bit from "Why *has* Bourbaki ignored..." to "Why *did* Bourbaki ignore...".  Normally this would be ambiguously wrong, but to the best of my knowledge Bourbaki is no longer writing :)

Comment: Thank you @Ryan for improving (correcting!) the title of my "Question". (I had some doubts myself too but was resigned to my inadequate English).

Comment: @Todd & @quid, when a good "Answer" appears to my "Question" then I feel a pressure to accept it without too much delay. I wish we could accept more than one "Answer". (And I truly liked @quid's answer).

Comment: @Ryan: I do not know if good old Nick is writing right now, but his newest book - the new edition of Algèbre VIII - appeared only last year.

Comment: @Wlod, nice question! And great to see you here :-) I learned much reading your posts on pl.sci.matematyka.

Comment: Hi Michał, nice to see you again! But the question is already closed as "... argumentative"--what's wrong with some guys? (I hoped to learn quite a bit more).

Comment: @Wlodzimierz Holsztynski: in general I think you should not feel any pressure to accept an answer quickly (waiting a or even several days is certainly fine, in particular for somewhat open or vaguer questions). But thanks for the positive feedback. Regarding closure, three things: first, please, do not be upset about it. second, if you want you'd be able to vote to reopen (as it is your own question and you have 250+ points, link below the question), third you can if you like start a thread on meta (link at the top, extra signup but easy and instant) presenting an argument for reopening. 

Comment: @quid, I'll be taking more time from now on before accepting an answer. Perhaps common sense should tell me this too. Thank you for your advice. About the closure, it'd be beneath me to try to reopen it (I prefer bitching about it :-). I am sorry to miss potentially more answers which would be so interesting to me.

Comment: @Wlodzimierz: some quick observations on "subjective and argumentative". I've been observing MO culture for a while; although I think the general question is interesting and worthwhile, the tone could suggest that you've already made up your mind what you think the answer should be. Also: a possibly problematic word is "ignore" (probably not literal, as all Bourbakistes were highly aware of categories). Asking "what is wrong with some guys?" and "preferring to bitch" might reinforce the impression of argumentativeness. (This is not to be critical; just pointing out possible red flags.) 

Comment: The person who would have introduced Bourbaki to categories was Charles Ehresmann.  He died in 1979 but he had a huge number of students, many of whom are still active, not least his widow, and could give an authoritative answer to this question.  They should be allowed and invited to do so.

Comment: Well, since very recently, the published Bourbaki treatise also introduces categories - cf. TA.II.3.1!

Comment: An interesting discussion about Bourbaki can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqR459KxDVU (in French). In particular, categories are mentioned.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind is that Bourbaki started in the 1930s, so in some sense simply *too early* to include category theory right from the start on, and foundational matters were rather fixed early on and then basically stayed like this. Since (I think) the aim was/is a *coherent* presentation (as opposed to merely a collection of several books in similar spirit) to change something like this 'at the root' should be a major issue.
Some 'add on' seems possible but just does not (yet) exist; and it seems the idea to write something like this was (perhaps is?) entertained (see below).

To support the above here is a quote from MacLane (taken from the [French Wikipedia page on Bourbaki](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) which contains a somewhat longer quote and source):

> Categorical ideas might well have fitted in with the general program of Nicolas Bourbaki [...]. However, his first volume on the notion of mathematical structure was prepared in 1939 before the advent of categories. It chanced to use instead an elaborate notion of an échelle de structure which has proved too complex to be useful. Apparently as a result, Bourbaki never took to category theory. At one time, in 1954, I was invited to attend one of the private meetings of Bourbaki, perhaps in the expectation that I might advocate such matters. However, my facility in the French language was not sufficient to categorize Bourbaki.

There it is also mentioned that (in the context of the influence of the lack of categories on the discussion of homological algebra, only for modules not for abelian categories):

> On peut lire dans une note de bas de page du livre d'Algèbre Commutative: « Voir la partie de ce Traité consacrée aux catégories, et, plus particulièrement, aux catégories abéliennes (en préparation) », mais les propos de MacLane qui précèdent laissent penser que ce livre « en préparation » ne sera jamais publié.

This translates to (my rough translation): One can read in a footnote of the book Commutative Algebra: "See the part of this Treatise dedicated to categories, and, more specificially, to abeliens categories (in preparation)", but the sentiments of Mac Lane expressed above [part of which I reproduced]  let one think that this book "in preparation" will never be published.

The precise reference for the footnote according to Wikipedia is N. Bourbaki, Algèbre Commutative, chapitres 1 à 4, Springer, 2006, chap. I, p. 55.

Comment: I find MacLane's statement not convincing. Samuel Eilenberg was a part of Bourbaki, could out-talk any Frenchman (fluency in French was not his problem). By 1956 he & Henri Cartan wrote Homological Algebra. Perhaps Bourbaki invested in its original approach so much that they were not willing to start a gigantic work again. What if there would be still a new revolution? And even the most energetic mathematicians have only so much time and energy, and not more. Bourbaki had no meritoric objections against theory of category, used and developed further theory of categories in their own research.

Comment: The quote (or rather it seems to be another quote of him) on the page by MacLane also contains "He [Bourbaki] was too conservative to recognize other better descriptions of structure when they arose [some references to category theory]". You say "invested in its original approach so much that they were not willing to start a gigantic work again" yes I would assume there were also practical considerations. This is what I meant with the issue of changing things at the root; eg, by the end of the 50s 'Algebra' (at least large parts thereof) and 'General Topology' already extisted. 

Comment: The article mention by Martin in a comment (on the question) is very interesting and discusses among others some practical considerations in some detail.

Answer (score 30):

As mentioned in a comment, there are some people such as Colin McLarty who I think could give an informed answer. I am not one of those persons, but since this question is likely to be closed soon, I will just mention a few helpful references.

One is McLarty's article [The Last Mathematician from Hilbert’s Gottingen: Saunder Mac Lane as Philosopher of Mathematics](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/30960789_The_Last_Mathematician_from_Hilbert%27s_Gottingen_Saunders_Mac_Lane_as_Philosopher_of_Mathematics). Indeed the members of Bourbaki invited Mac Lane to speak to them, but it probably wasn't Mac Lane's French that was the problem in getting them to incorporate category theory into the grand vision. Mac Lane and Weil were of course colleagues at the University of Chicago and presumably had ample opportunity to discuss category theory (in English); as quoted in McLarty's article, Weil writes to fellow Bourbakiste Chevalley in 1951:

> As you know, my honourable colleague Mac Lane maintains every notion of structure necessarily brings with it a notion of homomorphism, which consists of indicating, for each of the data that make up the structure, which ones behave covariantly and which contravariantly [...] what do you think we can gain from this kind of consideration?

McLarty explains in his article that Weil didn't understand Mac Lane. If I understand correctly, there were indeed opportunities to incorporate category theory within the Élements, specifically as part of an account of an abstract theory of structures, but (McLarty, page 5):

> After the war, Bourbaki hotly debated how to make a working theory. All agreed it must include morphisms. Members Cartier, Chevalley, Eilenberg, and Grothendieck championed categories, as did their visitor Mac Lane. But Weil was a majority of one in the group, so they created a theory with structure preserving functions as morphisms (Bourbaki [1958]). They never used it, and not for lack of trying.

Throughout the discussion of Bourbaki's (or Weil's) attitude toward categories, McLarty mentions the work of Leo Corry, who discusses Bourbaki's *structures* in his book [Modern Algebra and the Rise of Mathematical Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3764370025) (reviewed [here](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?service=UI&version=1.0&verb=Display&handle=euclid.rml/1081878080)). Related is a useful online article by Corry, published in Synthese, [here](http://www.tau.ac.il/~corry/publications/articles/pdf/bourbaki-structures-synthese.pdf). I won't attempt to summarize it, but there is discussion, on the basis of documents, of "the interaction between Bourbaki's work and the first stages of category theory".

---

**Edit:** Although the thread has closed and quid (user9072) has departed, Francois Ziegler recently brought to my attention in a comment below that Ralf Krömer ([2006](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2008b:01007); [pdf](//smf.emath.fr/publications/la-machine-de-grothendieck-se-fonde-t-elle-seulement-sur-des-vocables)) (subtitled *Bourbaki and categories during the 1950s*) has thoroughly investigated the OP’s question, using unpublished internal reports of the meetings of Bourbaki, as well as correspondence and quotes of e.g. Eilenberg (p. 142), Cartier (p. 147), Grothendieck (p. 149), and others. There is quite a rich treasure trove of well-sourced information there, for those who are interested.

Comment: While I'd agree there is something to Weil having some responsibility here, it is not quite clear to me how to reconcile this strong description in particular "But Weil was a majority of one in the group [...]" with what is generally said regarding the workings of the group (unanimity and alike) *and more importantly* the fact that Weil (officially) retired from Bourbaki in *1956*. (Addded: To stress this point of timeline let me recall that then Grothendieck was aged 28 and Cartier aged 24 [roughly] so they'd had plenty of time.)

Comment: It is indeed a strong description; this and the fact that it is perhaps a critical point of the discussion were reasons I singled it out. I'm not sure to what extent the usual rules of Bourbaki (retirement at age 50 etc.) applied to Weil, who I take to be something of a spiritus rector for the collective. I hope Colin will weigh in at some point; I emailed him before putting together this answer. 

Comment: @quid: regarding "mandatory requirement at age 50", see also the article by Aubin: http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~daubin/publis/1997.pdf. In particular, footnote 3 reads: "The historian Liliane Beaulieu, who has worked the most extensively on Bourbaki, told me that she had never come across any written trace of this rule and that *in any case it was breached many times*." (My emphasis) 

Comment: Weil was the *first* (while not oldest!) to apply them to himself by letting a letter announcing his retirement be read at the 50th birthday party of Dieudonné (born in 1906, like Weil). [See eg footnote 10 in article mentioned by Martin.]  So, at least officially he definitely retired, which is what I claimed. (To what extent his influence continued in a non-official way is not known to me; in case I find time I might reread parts of his correpondence with Cartan for hints.) [There are some other details about the quote I find surprising but I do not want to appear argumentative.] 

Comment: The above comment was written before I saw yours. I will leave it for practical reasons for the moment but study your source. Added after studying said source: it does not seem to contradict the claim Weil retired, which is also confirmed by a credible source (as already provided). The birthday detail is from elsewhere; I think I could refind it but this additional detail seems not very relevant anyway. 
I think I will stop now, at least for some time. But perhaps Godement will visit MO a second time and inform us first hand. This would be great. :-)    

Comment: @quid.  Why is it hard to reconcile Weil being (far) the strongest voice in the group with him following his own rule on retirement?  Of course we have much more from the Bourbaki archives now than when I wrote what I did.  But it remains that Bourbaki wrote up a theory of structures following what Weil said in 1951 he got from Mac~Lane, while the theory did not actually do what Mac~Lane (or Cartan or Chevalley or Grothendieck) wanted.  I am not clear what position Eilenberg took on it.

Comment: @Colin McLarty: what I meant to point out is that there is a so to say post-Weil period of Bourbaki that started in about the mid/end 50s. After that there *would* have been plenty of time to change things for *others*. And, now you mention 1951, and then let me get to another point I found surprising, the quote says: "Members Cartier, Chevalley, Eilenberg, and Grothendieck championed categories, as did their visitor Mac Lane. But Weil [...]" This juxtaposition give the impression that so to say everybody championed something except Weil and this happening at the same time and...   

Comment: ...and also it suggests there being a conflict. But in particular for Cartier and Grothendieck specifically with 1951 this hardly can be true. And, I am somewhat sensistive to this, since for example (digressing a bit) in this 'Bourbaki biography' by Aczel a picture is drawn that Grothendieck so to say left Bourbaki because of Weil and in general Weil is portrayed as some sort of villain of that story. Now, I have not carried out any actual historical studies relatred to this, but I read the Grothendieck-Serre correspondence and while there is mention of reasons why...    

Comment: ...Grothendieck somehow left/did not contribute much to Bourbaki (already relatively early) Weil does not seem to be the reason, but quite simply he (Gr.) simply was busy with his own projects and preferred to pursue them (instead). Or, also you quoting Gr. with Verflachung. But when did he say this? Three/four decades later. As said right at the start it might well be that then an (in retrospect) unfortunate diecision was made and even it might well be that Weil was responsible. But the presentation to me paints the picture of Weil somehow stubornly insisting on something while everbody...   

Comment: ...else knew better *at that point in time.* And this seems a bit implausible to me. In addition, but I might be over-sensitive here, to contributing to a in my opinion somewhat wide spread tendency of painting a generally negative picture of Weil.  

Comment: @quid.  You can research and write this history.  As to when Grothendieck spoke of "Verflachung" you need no rhetorical question: I give the date with the quote, and I give a footnote saying where he got the term.  In the Grothendieck Serre correspondence you must have noticed their complaints about Weil, and I will say I doubt that actually came from Serre though he goes along with it.  Serre understood (and understands) Weil very well.  I think it came from Grothendieck.  I am sure you are right that Grothendieck was also pulled away by his own projects. 

Comment: @Colin McLarty: Sorry, for the rhetorical question; I saw the reference and indeed calculated the timespan from it. I did not pay attention to my phrasing possibly suggesting the information was not present there. In some sense I would actually be interested to investigate certain things related to this in detail, but then I am a complete amateur as regards history and the question why at least in my opinion Weil is treated so relatively negatively at many places in contrast to Grothendieck might even be more sociology than history. Yet then maybe at some point in the distant future.      

Comment: Let me also stress that this is really meant as a very personal and amateurish opinion of mine. Perhaps I am completely wrong. It is more meant as a justifcation of me reacting relatively sensitive here.  

Comment: @quid  Well, yes Weil was a huge influence on all of modern pure mathematics.  But his most important contributions are very hard to grasp even today, and he is utterly underrated by people who only know his low level ideas as in Bourbaki. He was also a brilliant collaborator to people he respected.  But I know myself that to call him acerbic is an understatement.  He and Grothendieck eventually could not stand each other.  

Comment: @Colin McLarty: Thank you for the reply. Perhaps this is a good ending point for our discussion. (Also, I like the word 'acerbic', which I had not known before.)

Comment: @Todd Trimble: since I just stumbled over it, in case you are interested, the letter of retirement of Weil (to Cartan with the request to read it at the next congress) is in the Cartan-Weil correspondence (June 26th, 1956).

Comment: To elaborate on Leo Corry on Bourbaki's structures, my sense from reading Corry is that Bourbaki, and especially Weil, were albatrossed by their theory of "structures" which was hopelessly rooted in naive set theory, which created an obstacle for a rival foundational account given by category theory.

Comment: It would be worth mentioning (not just in this buried comment) that Krömer ([2006](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2008b:01007); [pdf](//smf.emath.fr/publications/la-machine-de-grothendieck-se-fonde-t-elle-seulement-sur-des-vocables)) (subtitled *Bourbaki and categories during the 1950s*) thoroughly investigates the OP’s question using unpublished internal reports, correspondence and quotes of e.g. Eilenberg (p. 142), Cartier (p. 147), Grothendieck (p. 149), etc.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Thanks. I haven't looked into this reference, and thus I don't know whether it is consonant or not with the conclusions drawn by McLarty and Corry. If it is not, then I don't see how I would smoothly integrate it into my answer -- but I am happy meanwhile to upvote your comment for visibility's sake.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler My command of French is not sufficient to read the text without some assistance, but it is very interesting and it does seem consonant with what I thought I understood from reading the essays by McLarty and Corry. And so I think I will make an edit to my answer, acknowledging your references. Just one note with regard to the commentary below my answer: it is noted that Weil was present at the 43rd meeting in 1957 (*after he announced his retirement in 1956*) in which they are discussing a possible Theory of Categories (for Bourbaki) -- see page 26 of 44 of the pdf.

Comment: Yes, 26th page of Krömer. His thesis ([2004](//tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00151000), pages numbered 334–335, omitted from the [translation](//ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2008d:01013)) further records Weil’s presence at meetings 44 (March 1958) and 51 (June-July 1960) which was Grothendieck’s (*and Weil’s?*) last. This seems to clearly settle your above debate with quid.

Answer (score 23):

These are good answers and I have nothing to add on the particular reasons.  To sum it up I would say it was impossible to write a comprehensive Elements of Mathematics based on category theory, because it is impossible to write a comprehensive Elements of Mathematics at all.  The brilliant attempt was very good for mathematics, I will maintain, but it could not really be done.

Categories and functors in the 1950s were developed only for immediate applications, and not as a general theory of structure.  It was very much easier for Bourbaki to develop a general theory that did not work, than to unify a sprawling mass of working methods into one theory.  And nothing was really going to work for their vast project anyway.

So far as I know no one talked about a general theory called "category theory" before biologist Robert Rosen in works like "A relational theory of the structural changes induced in biological systems by alterations in environment" Bull. Math. Biophys. 23 1961 165–171.

Answer (score 14):

It might be interesting to look at the Appendix to Exposé I of SGA 4. In a footnote this is described as follows:

*Nous reproduisons ici, avec son accord, des papiers secrets de N. BOURBAKI.*

While the appendix treats mainly the theory of universes, it makes use of the language of categories. Moreover, some internal references hint to the existence of some more "papiers secrets" containing a draft of a chapter about categories.

Answer (score 11):

I don't agree with  Wlodzimierz's general comments about chaos! In many aspects Bourbaki did a tremendous job in writing clear and clean mathematics,  but the aim which I think is professed of writing a complete and so to speak permanent account comes up against the evolving nature of the mathematical project. This is evident in many present and past attitudes to category theory.

A review for the MAA of the 1968 edition of my book "Elements of Modern Topology", now "Topology and Groupoids" (2006), suggested it read like a "book on topology written by a category theorist", and this was presumably not meant as a compliment! Many regarded its use of groupoids as a mistake. Compare a recent [review](http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/19/?pa=reviews&sa=viewBook&bookId=69421).  I would hope most mathematicians now recognise the enormous contribution category theory has made to the unity of mathematics, allowing analogies between constructions in quite disparate parts of the subject, through such terms as limit and colimit, as but one example.

I feel that the progress of mathematics is considerably helped by people trying to write complete, consistent  and clear accounts, so that the deficiencies  in the attempt, i.e. in current understanding,  become apparent.

Comment: I have written in my "Question" above: no fluke [Bourbaki] can overtake Chaos and Jungle. It's fine (almost mandatory :-) to contradict me, but I don't see any logic in your "disagreement" with my "general comments".